# Is it possible to tell a while loop to 'keep looping until this condition is not met, then execute one more time'?

Tags: javascript, while-loop

Here's my loop.

```
if (strSplit[i] == "(") {
    while (strSplit[i] != ")") {
        newElement = newElement.concat(strSplit[i]);
        i++;
    }
    /*add the closing bracket*/
    newElement = newElement.concat(strSplit[i]);
    i++;
}
```

So what we're doing is concatenating the elements in the array together such that it includes both the opening and closing round brackets.

I find it a bit inelegant that I have to repeat the concatenation one more time to add the closing bracket.

Is it possible to tell a while loop to 'keep looping until this condition is not met, then execute one more time'?

Comment: `if (strSplit[i] = "(")` is doing an assignment, not a comparison.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`do...while`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/do...while)

```
do{
    newElement = newElement.concat(strSplit[i]); i++;
}while(strSplit[i] != ")")
```

Comment: What's happening here? It concatinates the first element (the opening bracket), reaches the while statement and compares `strSplit[i]` to `")"` and THEN increments `i`?

Comment: I think the `i++` really belongs inside of the loop, otherwise you'll end up with an `i` that is one too high.

Comment: It first executes the codes inside the block, then it executes the condition `strSplit[i++] != ")"`. If it is `true` then it will go back. Meanwhile, it also increases `i` by one.

Comment: @basilikum - are you sure that's a problem? If you look at the original code - we want `i` to end up being one higher than the closing bracket index anyway.

Comment: @dwjohnston - `do..while` actually will make the counter go one higher (you can think of it that it starts at 1 instead of 0.)

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 - I think your updated answer doesn't work, it doesn't include the closing bracket.  See this paste for the implementation. http://pastebin.com/BPYhV9Mf

Answer (score 0):

You could just save the index of the "(" and the index of ")" (let's call the indexes `a` and `b`) and then get the substring from `a` to `b+1`

If you are feeling more adventurous you do some researches for "regular expressions" and find an even more elegant way to do that :)

Answer (score 0):

Or to "brute-force" the issue, inelegantly,  just add one more line of code after the while that is like what is inside the loop.

```
var count = 10;
var grow = '[';

while (count > 1)
  {
   grow = grow + count;
   count = count - 1;
   }

grow = grow + ']';

$('#putmehere').html(grow);
```